# ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger - additional errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a blank table for which I've set up a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER   authors_bir
BEFORE INSERT ON authors
FOR EACH ROW

begin
  if upper(:new.name) = 'TEST' then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sorry, that value is not allowed.');
  end if;
end;
```

After executing:

```
insert into AUTHORS
    VALUES (1, 'test', '1-Jan-1989', 'M');
```

Why am I getting ORA-06512 and ORA-04088 error messages in addition to the expected ORA-20001 error prompt?

**ErrorMessage**

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
insert into AUTHORS
    VALUES (1, 'test', '1-Jan-1989', 'M')
Error report -
ORA-20001: Sorry, that value is not allowed.
ORA-06512: at "RPS.AUTHORS_BIR", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RPS.AUTHORS_BIR'
```

Comment: Show us the schema of authors.

Comment: @anonyXmous hope this is what you're looking for? https://pastebin.com/X6usMe7m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger works perfectly and ORA-06512 is part of debugging mode and tells you what line of code raised that ORA-20001 that you coded. While ORA-04088 is saying that an error has occurred in the trigger. Both error codes are GENERIC part of oracle troubleshooting report.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e4100.htm):

> ORA-06512: at stringline string
>
> Cause: Backtrace message as the stack is unwound by unhandled exceptions.

Basically, this error is part of the error stack telling at which line the actual error occurred.

And [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e2100.htm):

> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'string.string'
>
> Cause: A runtime error occurred during execution of a trigger.

And this error is a part of the error stack telling you that error actually occurred in a trigger.

When an unhandled error occurs, error stack is always displayed. If you want to display just the error message, you could use an exception handling part so body of the trigger would look something like this:

```
begin
  if upper(:new.name) = 'TEST' then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sorry, that value is not allowed.');
  end if;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode|' '|sqlerrm);
end;
```